# LDAP - ldapmodify error when trying to add a new attribute

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have the following entry in LDAP directory:

```
dn: ou=Users,dc=itau,dc=co
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Users
```

Unfortunately, I forgot to add the `gid` attribute. Because of this, I had created the following LDIF file called "modify.ldif":

```
dn: ou=Users,dc=itau,dc=co
changetype: modify
add: gid
gid: 20000
```

But when I run the command

```
ldapmodify -x -D "cn=admin,dc=itau,dc=co" -w <PASSWORD> -H ldap:// -f modify.ldif
```

I get the error:

```
ldap_modify: Undefined attribute type (17)
additional info: gid: attribute type undefined
```

It's important to say that I had checked for blank spaces at the end of each line, but this error didn't desappear.

Why I'm getting this error?.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess gid attribute is not available for ObjectClass organizationalUnit

Comment: Please confirm whether the attribute name is gid or gidnumber... gidnumber is attribute is mostly applied to the posixGroup